# Need help identifying this promotional edition of Goosebumps HorrorLand book

Tags: goosebumps

I have a “*[Goosebumps HorrorLand: Revenge of the Living Dummy](https://goosebumps.fandom.com/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Living_Dummy)*” edition that is smaller (6 3/4” x 4 3/8”) than the original edition and only 93 pages. The back cover has an advertisement for HomeTown Buffet, Ryan’s & Old Country Buffet. The ISBN is 9780545552837.

I can’t find any info about it online. Are you able to tell me what it is? How many were released/produced? Possibly what some rough value is for it?

Comment: Valuation questions aren't off-topic (per se), but you're asking a bunch of different questions here. Try restricting yourself to a single one

Comment: It looks like this guy is selling it for a few dollars; http://www.258sd.com/goods/228010.html